# In Microsoft SQL Server, can one database have multiple schemas?

Tags: sql-server

What is the relationship between database and schemas in Microsoft SQL server?

I know in Oracle that on database can have multiple schemas. Is it the same in Microsoft SQL Server?

Comment: **Yes, OF COURSE!**  - just read the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/authentication-access/create-a-database-schema?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Thank you for the response. If I need to use one table across multiple schemas, should is set some access permissions at the table level?

Answer (score 1):

Full object name is: Server.Database.Schema.Object. Yes, you can multiple schemas in a database in SQL Server.